# How to calculate average for categories with ability to filter each category by different date?

Tags: filter, average, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

I am trying to create a filter where I can select different dates for different categories, and it will calculate the average (e.g sales) per category.

The reason for this is because different months can cause skews in the data for different categories, so will need to account for this. E.g Sales of oranges high in summer, therefore want an average across all seasons excluding summer. Sales of chocolate higher in december, therefore want to exclude december.

For example:

Apple = Avg 100 sales -- Filtered to Jan 2021, Feb 2021 and March 2021

Pear = Avg 400 sales -- Filtered to September 2021, October 2021, December 2021

So I would like one table with Category (e.g Apple) and Avg Sales.

| Category | Avg Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 100 |
| Pear | 400 |

Then a filter where for Apple > I can select the months I want the average based off.
For Pear, I want to select different months to base the average off etc.

If a filter doesnt work - i'm open to other suggestions. Would a parameter work?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX4CD.png)

I'm really struggling so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Manisha

Comment: Can you please share a Tableau Public workbook with some dummy data, its easier to solve that way

Comment: Hi - It won't let me publish the workbook for some reason (think my work account is being weird), but I've attached a screenshot from the sample-superstore data. 

What I need, is for Furniture's avg sales to be calculated by any month I want, e.g Jan feb march. And Office supplies to be calculated off another month i select, e.g October November December. The filter needs to be flexible and all needs to sit in one table like the image above.

Comment: No worries - I have a fix now! Created sheet for each category with filter.

Comment: This is more of a "Jugaad" than a fix , but I'm glad its solved